# Discord .NET API Bot - Commands not working

Tags: .net, discord.net

Since i am pretty new to .NET and programming in general, i got stuck while creating a bot with the Discord .NET API.

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Interactions;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class Program
{
    public static Task Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync();

    private static DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandHandler _commandHandler;
    private static CommandService _commands;
    

    public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _commandHandler = new CommandHandler(_client, _commands);
        await _commandHandler.InstallCommandsAsync();

        _client.Log += Log;

        var token = "XXXXXX";


        
        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await _client.StartAsync();
        
       
        

        // Block this task until the program is closed.
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    //--Commandhandler--//

    public class CommandHandler
    {
        private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private readonly CommandService _commands;

        // Retrieve client and CommandService instance via ctor
        public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService commands)
        {
            _commands = commands;
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task InstallCommandsAsync()
        {
            // Hook the MessageReceived event into our command handler
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;

            // Here we discover all of the command modules in the entry 
            // assembly and load them. Starting from Discord.NET 2.0, a
            // service provider is required to be passed into the
            // module registration method to inject the 
            // required dependencies.
            //
            // If you do not use Dependency Injection, pass null.
            // See Dependency Injection guide for more information.
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(assembly: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
                                            services: null);
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage messageParam)
        {
            // Don't process the command if it was a system message
            var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;
            if (message == null) return;

            // Create a number to track where the prefix ends and the command begins
            int argPos = 0;

            // Determine if the message is a command based on the prefix and make sure no bots trigger commands
            if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos) ||
                message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)) ||
                message.Author.IsBot)
                return;

            // Create a WebSocket-based command context based on the message
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

            // Execute the command with the command context we just
            // created, along with the service provider for precondition checks.
            await _commands.ExecuteAsync(
                context: context,
                argPos: argPos,
                services: null);
        }
    }

    public class InfoModule : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
    {
        // ~say hello world -> hello world
        [Command("say")]
        public Task SayAsync(string echo)
        {
           return ReplyAsync(echo);
        }

    }
    public class ExampleCommands : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
    {
        // dependencies can be accessed through Property injection, public properties with public setters will be set by the service provider
        public InteractionService Commands { get; set; }
        private CommandHandler _handler;

        // constructor injection is also a valid way to access the dependecies
        public ExampleCommands(CommandHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        // our first /command!
        [SlashCommand("8ball", "find your answer!")]
        public async Task EightBall(string question)
        {
            // create a list of possible replies
            var replies = new List<string>();

            // add our possible replies
            replies.Add("yes");
            replies.Add("no");
            replies.Add("maybe");
            replies.Add("hazzzzy....");

            // get the answer
            var answer = replies[new Random().Next(replies.Count - 1)];

            // reply with the answer
            await RespondAsync($"You asked: [**{question}**], and your answer is: [**{answer}**]");
        }
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


}
```

My problem is that the bot does not respond to the 2 command modules that i have already added in.
Some of this code is from the API-guide... the bot does not respond to these commands...

I have given it permission to Send messages, read message history and use slash commands.
Already tried adding in the .InstallCommandsAsync() in the Main but i don't know where to go from now. Am i not calling methods that i need to call in the main? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You've exposed your token, I'd suggest you get a new one and also move it to your appsettings.json file.

Comment: @IvanGechev that is an old token

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you got 2 mistakes here, class `InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>` is for slash commands not for text-based commands so your `HandleCommandAsync` task is gonna register only chat text-based commands and you dont have any handler and registration for slash commands also you should edit your MainAsync task invoking, according to documentation it should be `static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

About text-based commands:

- Class with commands have to inherit from `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>`

About slash commands(with attributes):

- Use `InteractionService`
- Use `IServiceProvider`
- Add modules and register commands
- Make handler for interactions(commands)
- To be sure everything works you should do this in `_client.Ready` event

Example:
Add using(update this package if necessary):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Proper Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Additional variables:

```
private static DiscordSocketClient _client;
private CommandHandler _commandHandler;
private static CommandService _commands;

private InteractionService _interactionService; //+
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider = CreateServices(); //+
```

Create services method:

```
static IServiceProvider CreateServices()
        {
            var config = new DiscordSocketConfig()
            {
                GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
            }; //This is only example config, feel free to make own
            
            var collection = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(config)
                .AddSingleton<DiscordSocketClient>();

            return collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

Adjust `MainAsync` Task:

```
    //_client = new DiscordSocketClient(); //Remove this
    //_commands = new CommandService(); //You can remove this too its not necessary for slash commands
    //_commandHandler = new CommandHandler(_client, _commands); //You can remove this too its not necessary for slash commands
    //await _commandHandler.InstallCommandsAsync(); //You can remove this too its not necessary for slash commands
    _client = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>(); //+

    _client.Ready += _client_Ready;
```

Finally add modules and interaction handling:

```
private async Task _client_Ready()
        {
            _interactionService = new InteractionService(_client);
            await _interactionService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _serviceProvider);
            await _interactionService.RegisterCommandsGloballyAsync();

            _client.InteractionCreated += async (x) =>
            {
                var ctx = new SocketInteractionContext(_client, x);
                await _interactionService.ExecuteCommandAsync(ctx, _serviceProvider);
            };
        }
```

Remove this code fragment as its unnecessary:

```
// dependencies can be accessed through Property injection, public properties with public setters will be set by the service provider
        public InteractionService Commands { get; set; }
        private CommandHandler _handler;

        // constructor injection is also a valid way to access the dependecies
        public ExampleCommands(CommandHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }
```

**To be sure i tested this, and slash command works perfectly. Also as i am testing text-based commands(after fixing inheritance) it works but only by calling bot by mention `@botmention say something` not by prefix so i dont know what causing this. Also if you want `say` command to be handling multiple words add remainder attribute like: `public Task SayAsync([Remainder]string echo)`**

Sources:
https://discordnet.dev/guides/concepts/events.html
https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/application-commands/slash-commands/creating-slash-commands.html
https://discordnet.dev/guides/dependency_injection/basics.html
https://discordnet.dev/guides/dependency_injection/services.html
https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html